# How to build an automated classifier selection procedure?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, model-selection, model

I am working on a time series data based on remote sensing. I have applied different classification methods on data like RF, SVM, KNN, Gradient Boosting, etc. So, I have got different models and I know their accuracies and all statistics individually on all the classes.

Now, I want to build an automated method which just loops over these classifiers and check all the aspects of model selection and finally give me result which classifier is best for this data. I want to do this because I have a lot of different time series data files on different regions and I want to write a python script which gives me best classifier on each data files so that I can use each of them to predict my test data.
And yes, I can't append the different data file in one file because it will alter my results.

Please suggest me ways to do this. Also, I want to know what type of classifier selection aspects I can consider.